# Detect div change after page refresh javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reload

I have a page that displays a table with numbers. These are the prices my partner sees in the store. This page is specially made for him.

Prices change often. I enter prices in WordPress. I created Custom Post Type and a simple form to enter these numbers. One price = one custom field. The number of fields is around 30.

And it works great. But I need to detect the price change.
I would like the site for my partner clearly show the price change.

The ideal situation is when the DIV with new price has a changed color, and next to it appears a button to reset its color.
Such a mechanism will allow you to quickly find out about price changes.
This page is refreshed every 10 seconds.

I know the basics of JS, but I do not know how to do it. I suspect you will need to use SessionStorage.
Can anyone give me directions or paste a link to similar solution?

---

I have a lot of divs such as:

```
<div id="price1">[types field='price1'][/types]</div>
```

and JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 10000);

var price1 = document.getElementById('price1').textContent;

sessionStorage.setItem("price1-box", "price1");

var handle_storage = function () {
        console.log('change in storage! new' + price1);
      };

window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);
```

Comment: I see no code? Please show us your code and explain the exact error you are having. If you are unable to do that then you are best hiring a developer.

Comment: Yes, sessionStorage would probably be best.  But to retrieve the newest prices, maybe you'd like to use an ajax call to get the newest prices, then populate the price table and determine the color of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I made o solution. Maybe it will be useful to someone else.

```
<div id="eur-k">123</div>


window.onload = function() {

    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.reload(1);
    }, 30000);

    // define div to add or remove alert
    var eurkDiv = document.getElementById('eur-k');

    // store current content in a variable
    var eurk = eurkDiv.textContent;

    // compare local storage with current content to make alarm
    if (localStorage.getItem('eurkLoc') != eurk) {
        eurkDiv.classList.add("active");
        eurkDiv.innerHTML = eurk + "<button type=\"button\" class=\"potwierdzenie\" onclick=\"resetFunction()\">OK</button>";
    }

    function resetFunction() {
        eurkDiv.classList.remove("active");
        eurkDiv.textContent = eurk;
        localStorage.setItem('eurkLoc', eurk);
    };
};
```